# How to stop scanning of war files during deployment on jboss

Tags: jboss5.x

During deployment the jboss deployer scans all jars inside wars it slows down the deployment.

how to stop that so that deployment speed improves.

regards
Shreyas

Answer (score 0):

Project -> Properties -> Validation -> Configure Workspace settings

Disable all in Build column, except for App Client and classpath

Comment: @shreyas is talking about an application server... what are you talking about?

Comment: you're right. I was talking about eclipse running as an app server :)

Comment: i am taking around 2 hours to start jboss on windows 7 64 bit

Comment: in eclipse console it showed jboss started in 94 minutess but server view it showed status as staring. i had increased timeout to 10,000 seconds.then it said cannot start in 10,000 seconds timeout expired.

Comment: That should no happen. How many files are there under the war dir? You really need all them? Are there data files that could be moved outside the war?

Comment: Hi not much jars in war directories but i have quite a no of jars in two ears that are added to jboss. around 500 jars in total of two ears.

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem with JBoss 6. Still no idea how to fix it there, but about Jboss 5, looks like there is a special conf file where you can minimize scanning. Read this wiki page: [JBoss5 custom metadata files](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss5custommetadatafiles/version/4), there is a sample of such a configuration, maybe it helps